# jquery .load() url to target dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, load

i have got

```
<div><a class='link' href='index.php' data-container='target'>Load</a></div>
<div class='target'></div>
```

i need to write jquery code which load href url to data-container attribute

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.data-container).load(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data` like this:

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.' + $(this).data('container')).load(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).data('container');
    $('.'+ container).load(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I reply to my own question to clear solution and make it better

```
<div><a class='link' href='index.php' data-target='.target-class'>Load</a></div>
<div class='target-class'></div>

<div><a class='link' href='index.php' data-target='#target-id'>Load</a></div>
<div id='target-id'></div>
```

jQuery script, I use fix from Claudio as a base for my modification (Blaster is the same but shorter)

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).load(this.href);
});
```